# Not able to access resource from kubernates operator

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rbac, fabric8, k8s-cluster-role

I am getting below error when I try to fetch resource(test-associations) which is created by assocOperator(kubernates operator deployed at stage level) in testns2 namespace from test-operator code (which is kubernates operator deployed at stage level) . Could some one please help what I am  missing here?

Error :

> io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure
> executing: GET at:
> https://172.17.0.1/apis/tc.secassoc/v1/namespaces/testns2/associations/test-associations.
> Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access.
> Service account may have been revoked. associations.tc.secassoc
> "test-associations" is forbidden: User
> "system:serviceaccount:test-operator:test-operator" cannot get
> resource "associations" in API group "tc.secassoc" in the
> namespace "testns2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add proper RBAC permission to your operator's service account (i.e.`test-operator`).

If you're already creating a `ClusterRole` and a `ClusterRoleBinding` for the operator's service account. Make sure that the following rule exists in your `rules` section of `ClusterRole`:

```yaml
rules:
- apiGroups: ["tc.secassoc"]
  resources: ["associations"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

If you are not creating any of the RBAC resources, create the followings:

1. Create Cluster Role:

```yaml
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: associations-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: ["tc.secassoc"]
  resources: ["associations"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

```bash
$ kubectl apply -f cluster-role.yaml
```

2. Create Cluster Role Binding:

```bash
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding associations-reader-pod \
  --clusterrole=associations-reader  \
  --serviceaccount=test-operator:test-operator
```